# jQuery select body element from string

Tags: jquery

I have a string `<html><head></head><body>test</body></html>` and I'm trying to get just the contents of the body using jQuery.

Ive tried

```
$('<html><head></head><body>test</body></html>').find('body').html();
```

but that doesn't work.

Any ideas on how to do it?

Edit:

In case it wasn't clear, I need to get the body element from a **string**, not the DOM.

Edit 2:

Be aware that the method used needs to not return anything form the `head` element. Such as inline styles.

Comment: You are best off using an XML parser.  See my answer below.  Using jQuery suffers from the fact that it is constrained to the same DOM rules as the browser.  I.e. you cannot create a `body` element once the page has been loaded.

Comment: @Jeff, but Im using HTML, not XML.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var x = '<html><head></head><body>test</body></html>';
x = x.split("<body")[1].split(">").slice(1).join(">").split("</body>")[0];
alert(x);
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/6hPHn/1/

Comment: That'll do, I can still find a few edge cases that it will fail, but oh well.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to like that sort of HTML being passed into the jQuery functions, possibly because `html` is the parent element of a HTML document.

It even doesn't work using native DOM API...

```
var a = document.createElement('div');
a.innerHTML = '<html><head></head><body>test</body></html>';
console.log(a.innerHTML); // test
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SCpPE/) of difference between your string and others.

You could use a regular expression...

```
var str = '<html><head></head><body class="here is some classes">test\ntesty</body></html>';
str = str.replace(/^.*?<body.*?>([\s\S]*?)<\/body>.*?$/, '$1');
console.log(str); // test
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dQD9Q/).

Comment: That kinda works, but not really. Try `$('<div />').append('<html><head>test</head><body>test</body></html>').html()`

Comment: @Petah It doesn't seem to like the `html` element, check out the fiddles.

Comment: Your regex seems to be invalid

Comment: Yea, its says `SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag s`

Comment: Cool, now it almost works, but it fails if there is attributes on the body tag.

Comment: @Petah Yep, and seeing as your example didn't have any, I didn't take them into account. See edit.

Comment: Your great alex, alright one more challenge. It fails if I have html in a data attribute on the body tag.

Comment: @Petah Yeah, that is a limitation of HTML and regex. If you know it is constant, you can right a regex around it. Can you post what it looks like?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @RustyTheBoyRobot's answer, using RegEx would work best.  It would be far faster than using jQuery to create all of those DOM elements anyway.  Try something like this:

```
var html_page_string = '<html><head></head><body>test</body></html>';
var matches = html_page_string.match(/<body>(.*)<\/body>/ig);
```

The text you want should be in `matches[1]`

**EDIT**

For some reason, removing the `g` flag seemed to make it group correctly so that the string was in `matches[1]`:

```
var matches = html_page_string.match(/<body>(.*?)<\/body>/i);
```

Comment: Well the regex almost works, but can you make it strip the body tags as well.

Comment: @Petah `matches[1]` won't contain the `body` element as it is not part of the capturing group.

Comment: @alex this SHOULD be the case... but for some reason: see my edit.

Comment: `(.*)` will not match new lines.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your HTML string is valid strict XML and you are using jQuery 1.5, you can use the $.parseXML function.

```
$($.parseXML('<html><head></head><body><div>test</div></body></html>'))
.find("body").contents()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the .contents() method.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>Test</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var s = contents('body');
document.write(s);
```

^-- outputs "Test".

[See it working here.](http://jsfiddle.net/niczak/y6Jxy/)

Comment: You missed the part where I said I need to get the body from a string.

Comment: And, also that doesn't work at all. `contents is not defined`

Comment: @Petah: .contents() is a method that was added to jQuery in v1.2 -- what version are you using?  Doesn't matter if it is coming from a string or from the DOM, the method works in both cases.

Comment: Did you mean `$(element).contents()`

Answer (score 0):

never tried using `<body>`

i usually load a #ID element, just like

```
$('#where').load('file/path.php?bla?ble=bli #ID');
```

If this doesn't help, sorry, i didn't get your point..

by the way, for your exaple would work if:

> ```
> <html><head></head><body><div id="ID">test</div></body></html>
> ```

if it helps..

Comment: Not quite what Im doing. I have a `textarea` with the html in. And I want to strip out everything that is not in the body.

Comment: Well, the problem with the edit is, I don't have control over the contents of the string. So I cannot guarantee that there will be a `div` in the `body`

Comment: but did you tried with $('where').load('what body'); ? if not, maybe there is a way, wich i would really like to find out

Answer (score 0):

jQuery throws out the `<html>/<head>/<body>` tags.  If you had any nested elements, those would be parsed:

`$('<html><head></head><body><div>test</div></body></html>').find('body').html();`

Will give you "test", because after parsing, you have a `div` element.  Calling `.html()` returns the html in the `div`.

A quick hack to get the body then would be:

```
var tmp = $('<div></div>').append('<html><head></head><body>test</body></html>');

console.log(tmp.html());
```

**EDIT:**

After reading your update about head elements...  If you want a hack, just regex out the `body`.  And before you attack, I know, regex is not meant to parse html, but in this case, we assume there should be only one set of `body` tags, and those tags should be fairly simple.

Basically, I replaced everything up to the `<body>` tag with `<div id="hack"> and everything from``to the end of the string with``.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/m79tv/

Comment: Your quick hack fails on content in the head (such as inline styles)

Comment: New version.  Uses regex.  Works great now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My solution was to replaceAll('body>','xbody>') in my string and then I could use $(mystring).find('xbody')

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

My guess is that what you are wanting to accomplish would be easiest with a regex.

```
var html = $("#htmlInput").val();  //Grab what's in your textbox
html = html.replace(/.*<body[ A-Za-z0-9\="'\(\);]*>/i, "");
html = html.replace(/<\/body>.*/i, "");
```

This regex should be able to strip out everything but the contents of the body tags, even if there are attributes in the body tag.

Comment: Sorry, but you are wrong. Try `$('<div><h1>header</h1><p>para</p></div>').find('p').html()`